# How to organize Keys per application/domain in Redis Cache?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

Using Redis (Azure Redis Cache) for caching. I would like to organize my keys based on application/domain. How do i achieve this while using Redis Cache? Can someone elaborate whether usage of Databases and/or namespaces can help? IF so provide examples of how to use a Database and Namespaceing the keys?

SO looking at something like Application->Feature->KeyName like so.

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66682915/redis-namespaces-for-multi-tenant-apps)
However, I will keep this question open to see if this attracts other responses. Thanks for the SO community!

> So there are multiple things that you can do:

- You can prefix the keys with app name like app1:userid:uuid etc
- You can use different in memory db provided by redis. Redis supports upto 16 DBs.
- You can store keys for different apps in different db. To fetch them
  connect with respective DB.
- You can use both of the above methods.