# What are the disadvantages of using multiple databases in a single Redis instance for multiple tenants

Tags: caching, redis, multi-tenant, redis-cache

I'm trying to create a **multi-tenant application** and which will be **hosted in a single instance**. To complete this application I need to implement a Redis cache system. I have two solutions for multi-tenant caching. They are,

1. I **can prefix the keys** with tenant name like tenant1:myKey etc
2. I **can use different in-memory DB** provided by Redis. I can store different tenant details in different DB. To fetch them connect with the respective DB.

If I go with the second option, is there any **disadvantages/performance issue**? and if you can suggest any other solutions please help me!!

**Note**: I don't want to use Redis clustering

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43244958/why-using-multiple-database-in-same-instance-a-bad-idea-in-redis/43247589#43247589) might be helpful.

Comment: Yeah.. I have gone through it. But I couldn't see any serious disadvantages of using multiple databases. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192469/how-to-namespace-keys-on-redis-to-avoid-name-collisions/39193262#39193262 also helpful. But I'm not satisfied with these answers because I need little more explanations for the advantages and disadvantages.